# How do I access the correct NSManagedObjectContext from Mogenerator generated human files?

Tags: objective-c, macos, mogenerator

I'm trying to follow the directions in the top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005688/how-to-auto-increment-reference-number-persistently-when-nsmanagedobjects-created) question and I'm getting an error trying to access the **moc** variable. I know that it's supposed to be a managed object context, but I can't seem to figure out how to get access to it.

The file that I'm adding the -awakeFromInsert code is the "human" file generated by running mogenerator v1.22. I have a feeling that mogenerator populates some property with the correct managed object context but that it's not called moc. I could be totally off-base though so feel free to school me!

Comment: you really need to post some code, plus explain what "error" you're getting before anyone can help. Mogenerator files are simply NSManagedObject subclasses and they have nothing to do with managed object contexts (apart from the fact that they need one to exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mogenerator does not add a method named moc.  It's simply making subclasses of NSManagedObjects that contain accessors for convenience.  Since they subclasses of NSManagedObject you can use the -managedObjectContext method to access the context that the object is associated with.  So changing your -moc calls to -managedObjectContext should do the trick.